# Is this expansion possible $(f+g)(t)= f(t)+g(t)$?

Tags: functions, special-functions, functional-equations

If the functions were polynomials, is $(f+g)(t)= f(t)+g(t)$ possible?
I am trying to integrate a function of that form.

Answer (score 11):

This is precisely the definition of addition for functions. That is, if $f$ and $g$ are functions, then we *define* the expression $(f + g)(t)$ by the equation

$$(f + g)(t) = f(t) + g(t)$$